# Tenho problemas com esse formulario pra passar os dado pelo meio de PHP, mas não consigo o erro

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

Tenho esse form dentro de um modal de bootstrap;

```
<form action="form_handler.php" method="get" name="precioUpdate">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="venbras_actual_venta" class="col-xs-12 form-control-label">Precio actual de venta:</label>
    <label for="venbras_actual_venta" class="col-xs-12 form-control-label" id="venbras_modal_venta"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label for="venbras_modal_update_venta" class="form-control-label">Nuevo precio de venta:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="update_venta" value="000" id="update_venta" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="venbras_actual_compra" class="col-xs-12 form-control-label">Precio actual de compra:</label>
    <label for="venbras_actual_compra" class="col-xs-12 form-control-label" id="venbras_modal_compra"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Nuevo precio de compra:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
  </div>
</form>
```

E esto tentando simplesmente de mostrar o valor de um dos campos mas da erro de Undefined variable. E esse é o codigo do php pra mostrar os valores do form

```
<?php 
 $precioNuevo = $_GET['update_venta'];
 echo $precioNuevo;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente está faltando um botão de enviar dentro do formulário, se o botão estiver fora do `form` ou se estiver usando apenas um link, os dados não são enviados:

```
<form action="form_handler.php" method="get" name="precioUpdate">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="venbras_actual_venta" class="col-xs-12 form-control-label">Precio actual de venta:</label>
    <label for="venbras_actual_venta" class="col-xs-12 form-control-label" id="venbras_modal_venta"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label for="venbras_modal_update_venta" class="form-control-label">Nuevo precio de venta:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="update_venta" value="000" id="update_venta" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="venbras_actual_compra" class="col-xs-12 form-control-label">Precio actual de compra:</label>
    <label for="venbras_actual_compra" class="col-xs-12 form-control-label" id="venbras_modal_compra"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <label for="recipient-name" class="form-control-label">Nuevo precio de compra:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  <div>
</form>
```

Caso vá usar Ajax, o cuidado a se observar é usar o método correto (por exemplo `GET` para `$_GET[]` e `POST` para `$_POST[]`.